# CSS Setting an anchor img source

Tags: css

Say I have a link as follows :

```
                <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
```

Is it possible in css to set the img attribute of this a link so in the end would look like :

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
```

Like I tried

a img {
   background-color: black;
}

but no joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to set a background to your anchor?

```
a.addthis_button_facebook { background:url('twitter.png') no-repeat; display:block; width:32px; height:32px; }
```

Although to be fair... A facebook button should use facebook icon ;)

Comment: nah that was just example i am trying to set an img to my anchor

Comment: I have not getting expected result the image appears tiny whereas manually setting img src it appears normal size

Comment: @StevieB edited my answer, change `width` and `height` to the icon size you are trying to set

Comment: Its like repeating the image multiple times to full in the block, looks pretty weird ha...urgh this is a nightmare ! I am just looking for a way no to specify the img in the mark up but in the css

Comment: @StevieB, if you want it to be inline with other elements on the page then you should use `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: ok last problem seems to be i have verticle align middle in this div, but all these anchor images are leaning towards the top how can i align the vertically centre aswell. I tried putting align verticle middle on the above css but no joy

Comment: @StevieB could you update the markup in your question along with the div?

Comment: @StevieB, you will need to add a `line-height` to the `div`. Based on the height of the div the `line-height` will help you to vertically align the content to the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can define background images in anchor tag and give to padding left and give line height according to images height as like this .

**Css**

```
.addthis_button_facebook{
    background:url('http://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    padding-left:60px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:50px;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook">Hello this is your link</a>​
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/PQ4q2/

Answer (score 1):

There is no "img" attribute of a link.

If you're just trying to use an image as the link, why not do it the way you have it in your second block, with the `img` tag inside of the `a` tag?

To set the image as the background using CSS, you could do

```
a.addthis_button_facebook {
    background-image:url('twitter.png');
}
```

Comment: Because I was looking for a way to see the img source in CSS rather than the mark up